# Toggling between buttons not working Angular 4

Tags: html, angular

I am developing an angular 4 application in which I have created an html page containing two buttons for navigation. The page contains mainly two div sections. Clicking the Table button should ideally show the table div and clicking on chart button should show the chart div. At a time only one div should be rendered. At the moment clicking on it is not taking me to the div section. How do I achieve this in Angular 4.

results.component.html - main page
net-present-value-analysis - rendered within the results html

**UI**

[image]

**results.html**

```
<app-assumptions-summary></app-assumptions-summary>

<app-base-strategy></app-base-strategy>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 test_feasibility--accordion">
        <!-- Accordion -->
        <div id="accordion" role="tablist">

          <app-net-present-value-analysis></app-net-present-value-analysis>

          <app-economic-value-analysis></app-economic-value-analysis>

          <app-stress-test-analysis></app-stress-test-analysis>

          <app-ending-surplus-analysis></app-ending-surplus-analysis>

        </div><!-- Accordion End -->
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**results.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-results',
  templateUrl: './results.component.html'
})
export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**net-present-value-analysis.html**

```
<div class="card">
            <!-- Net Present Value Analysis -->
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="npva_heading">                                            
                <a [ngClass]="{'collapsed': !isExpanded}" data-toggle="collapse" href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="isExpanded = !isExpanded" role="button" [attr.aria-expanded]="isExpanded" aria-controls="accordion1" >
                    <h5 class="mb-0">Net Present Value Analysis</h5>
                </a>                                           
            </div>
             <div [ngClass]="{'show': isExpanded}" id="accordion1" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="accordion1_heading" data-parent="#accordion"  [attr.aria-expanded]="isExpanded" style="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" id="table-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#base-strategy-table--npva" role="tab" aria-controls="table" aria-selected="true">Table</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" id="chart-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#base-strategy-chart--npva" role="tab" aria-controls="chart" aria-selected="false">Chart</a>
                        </li>                                   
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                        <!-- NPVA table -->
                        <div  class="tab-pane base-strategy-table fade show active" id="base-strategy-table--npva" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="table-tab">
                            <div class="tb-container col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                                <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6"></div>
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6"><a href="#projection">View Projection</a></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                                        <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6"></div>
                                        <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6"><h6>Captive Option</h6></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Premium Paid</div>
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">-142,927</div>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Tax Deduction</div>
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">57,171</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Loan to Parent</div>
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">0</div>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Capital Contribution/Distribution</div>
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">-2500</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Dividend Distribution</div>
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">0</div>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Terminal Value</div>
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">9,997</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row net-cost">
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Net Cost</div>
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">-78,198</div>
                                </div>
                                <!--Commercial Option-->
                                <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6"></div>
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6"><h6>Commercial Option</h6></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Premium paid</div>
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">-142,927</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Tax Deduction</div>
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">57,171</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row net-cost">
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Net Cost</div>
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">-85,756</div>
                                </div> 
                                <!--Self Insurance Option-->
                                <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6"></div>
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6"><h6>Self Insurance Option</h6></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Discounted Losses Paid</div>
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">-141,901</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Discounted Tax Deduction</div>
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">48,174</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row net-cost">
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6">Net Cost</div>
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">-72,260</div>
                                </div>                                   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- NPVA table -->
                        <!-- NPVA Chart -->
                        <div  class="tab-pane base-strategy-chart fade" id="base-strategy-chart--npva"  role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="chart-tab">
                            <div class="tb-container col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                                <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-6"></div>
                                    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-6">Graph comes here
                                        <boxplotchart>
                                        </boxplotchart>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- NPVA Chart End -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- Card + Net Present Value Analysis End-->
```

**net-present-value-analysis.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { BoxPlotComponent } from "../../../../shared/HighCharts/BoxPlotChart";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-net-present-value-analysis',
  templateUrl: './net-present-value-analysis.component.html',
})
export class NetPresentValueAnalysisComponent implements OnInit {

  isExpanded = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: I can't imagine a page of code is necessary to demonstrate an issue with a toggle button. Please remove the code that is not related to the problem.

Comment: I am new to angular and not 100 percent sure what is needed and whats not. I have added the relevant pages that affect the toggle.

Comment: That's not related to Angular, that's basic debugging technique. Create a reproduction in http/stackblitz.com and them try to remove as much code as possible that doesn't make the error go away. That's your job as developer, you can't delegate that do people on StackOverflow.

Comment: Please find the stackblitz link though the css hasnt been applied as i mentioned its a bit difficult applying as too many files involved  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwvj8t?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts